# Ansible and GCP Using facts GCP filestore module

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, ansible, bucket

EDIT: I can use gcloud but cannot see how to get ip in var.

```
gcloud filestore instances describe nfsxxxd --project=dxxxxt-2xxx --zone=xxxx-xx-b --format='get(networks.ipAddresses)'

['1xx.x.x.1']
```

I'am tring to create filestore and mount it in instance.
I facing an issue when trying to get ipadress of this new filestore.

I'am using ansible module and I can see output when using -v in ansible command.

Ansible module filestore:

```
- name: get info on an instance
  gcp_filestore_instance_info:
    zone: xxxxx-xxxx-b
    project: dxxxxx-xxxxxx
    auth_kind: serviceaccount
    service_account_file: "/root/dxxxt-xxxxxxx.json"
```

Ansible output:

```
ok: [xxxxxx-xxxxxx] => {"ansible_facts": {"discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python3"}, "changed": false, "resources": [{"createTime": "2021-03-12T13:40:36.438598373Z", "fileShares": [{"capacityGb": "1024", "name": "nfxxxxx"}], "name": "projects/xxx-xxxxx/locations/xxxxxxx-b/instances/xxxxx-xxx", "networks": [{"ipAddresses": ["1xx.x.x.x"], "modes": ["MODE_IPV4"], "network": "admin", "reservedIpRange": "1xx.x.x.x/29"}], "state": "READY", "tier": "BASIC_HDD"}, {"createTime": "2021-03-10T11:13:00.111631131Z", "fileShares": [{"capacityGb": "1024", "name": "nfsnxxxxx", "nfsExportOptions": [{"accessMode": "READ_WRITE", "ipRanges": ["xxx.xx.xx.xxx"], "squashMode": "NO_ROOT_SQUASH"}]}], "name": "projects/dxxx-xxxxx/locations/xxxxx/instances/innxxxx", "networks": [{"ipAddresses": ["x.x.x.x."], ...
```

I have tried this but it doesn't works.
Ansible tasks:

```
- name: print fact filestore
  debug:
     msg: "{{ansible_facts.resources.createTime}}"

fatal: [nxxxxxxx]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'resources'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/root/xxxxxxx/tasks/main.yml': line 11, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: print fact filestore\n  ^ here\n"}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I believe the example output from your answer, the info is returned in a `resources` key in your task result. I cannot test myself, but I believe the following should meet your expectation.

Please note that `resources` is a list of dicts. In my below example I will access the info from the first element of the list. If you need someting else (e.g. list of all `createTime`...) or to loop over those objects, you can extend from this example.

```yaml
- name: get info on an instance
  gcp_filestore_instance_info:
    zone: xxxxx-xxxx-b
    project: dxxxxx-xxxxxx
    auth_kind: serviceaccount
    service_account_file: "/root/dxxxt-xxxxxxx.json"
  register: instance_info

- name: show create time for first resource
  debug:
    msg: "{{ instance_info.resources.0.createTime }}"

- name: show first ip of first network of first resource
  debug:
    msg: "{{ instance_info.resources.0.networks.0.ipAddresses.0 }}"
```

Comment: Perfect dear it's working fine, but I trying to get ipAddresses but it doesn't work. Do you know how to get it please ? "{{ instance_info.resources.0.networks }} works fine but tried this do not works "{{ instance_info.resources.0.networks.ipAddresses }}"

Comment: Please pay attention to my example but above all to your data. `networks` is a list, so is `ipAddresses`.

Comment: PERFECT, you should edit official doc of Ansible :D. Thx you helped me a lot.

Comment: `you should edit official doc of Ansible` => why me ? You can propose a PR for that yourself. After all you are the one using the module not me ;)

Comment: Because you're a Jedi master and i'am just a simple Padawan :)

Comment: Proposing PRs for doc, bugfixes, etc... is a very good way to start mastering new skills.

Comment: Dear just one last question, I have 3 elements and if I want to access to other element how can I get it ? tried this but doesn't works. "{{ instance_info.resources.1.networks.1.ipAddresses.1}}"

Comment: 3 elements at which level ? resources ? networks ? ipAddresses ? In your last example, you are fetching the second ip address of the second network in the second recource. Does this exist ?

Comment: yes dear I have 3 filestore that's why I have tried with '2' or '1'.

Comment: Do these filestores each have 2 networks ? and does the second network always have 2 IPs ? I suspect your are looking for `instance_info.resources.1.networks.0.ipAddresses.0` and `instance_info.resources.2.networks.0.ipAddresses.0`.

Comment: No I have one resources  but 3 networks, ip etc. I'm thinking what using this module it's not the rigth solution, because if new filestore are created in project, number of instance will move, for example filestore in .0 will be another because resources are ordered by name. May be I should use gcloud  command and specify the name of filestore to get ip to mount it

Comment: accessing data by their index when it can vary is not the right solution. This usually a good indication you should use loops, data extraction, etc.... but this is going beyond the current question and you should explain more precisely what you are trying to do exactly. This should probably go in an other question.

Comment: You're rigth I will post another question

Comment: Dear please find new question :D  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66619952/creation-gcp-ressource-and-get-ip-adresse]