# Creation GCP ressource and get IP adresse

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ansible, nexus

I must create new nexus server on GCP. I have decided to use nfs point for datastorage. All must be done with ansible ( instance is already created with terraform)

I must get the dynamic IP setted by GCP and create the mount point.

It's working fine with gcloud command, but how to get only IP info ?

Code:

```
- name: get info
  shell: gcloud filestore instances describe nfsnexus --project=xxxxx --zone=xxxxx --format='get(networks.ipAddresses)'
  register: ip


- name: Print all available facts
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "{{ip}}"
```

result:

```
ok: [nexus-ppd.preprod.d-aim.com] => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": {
        "ansible_facts": {
            "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python3"
        },
        "changed": true,
        "cmd": "gcloud filestore instances describe nfsnexus --project=xxxxx --zone=xxxxx  --format='get(networks.ipAddresses)'",
        "delta": "0:00:00.763235",
        "end": "2021-03-14 00:33:43.727857",
        "failed": false,
        "rc": 0,
        "start": "2021-03-14 00:33:42.964622",
        "stderr": "",
        "stderr_lines": [],
        "stdout": "['1x.x.x.1xx']",
        "stdout_lines": [
            "['1x.x.x.1xx']"
        ]
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: The commented out lines already have the IP: `"stdout": "['1x.x.x.1xx']"`.

Comment: Correct :D , I'am looking for getting stdout to register it in var. Should use someting line "{{ip.stdout}}" ?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the proper format string, eg. to get the first IP:

```
--format='get(networks.ipAddresses[0])'
```

Comment: Dear it's return blank line. my initial command used works fine, I need just to get correct return from ansible result

Answer (score 0):

Find solution just add this:

```
- name:
  debug:
    msg:  "{{ip.stdout_lines}}"
```

I'am feeling so stupid :(, I must stop to work after 2h AM :)

Thx